# How to get Pytest to identify iteration number when looping test function

Tags: python, testing, pytest, random-seed

I'm using pytest for this test I am doing.

I want to do the same test multiple of times, while altering the seed input. This randomises the test variables, which i thought was a good idea. That way, if the test fails, i can easily recreate the same test in a different environment to see what failed, using the same seed input:

```py
def test_foo():
    for i in range(0, 10):
        foo = random_foo('something', seed = i)

        assert subject_value(foo) == expected_value(foo)
```

However, if the test fails, Pytest won't tell me the value of `i` for when the AssertionError occurred, which makes debugging close to impossible. Any way to successfully do this? Or is this bad test code structuring, which in that case, any better methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That test code structure is called a *subtest*. In your case, each iteration of the loop should be a new subtest.

You're probably looking for the [subtests plugin](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-subtests/).

```
import subtests

def test_foo():
    for i in range(10):
        with subtests.test(msg="seed", i=i):  # Add what you need to see here.
            foo = random_foo('something', seed=i)

            assert subject_value(foo) == expected_value(foo)
```

Note that the standard library `unittest.TestCase` class [already has](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#distinguishing-test-iterations-using-subtests) support for subtests using `with self.subTest()` (since Python 3.4). Pytest can run these standard test cases as well.

---

Also, if you're interested in randomized test inputs in particular, you might be interested in [Hypothesis](https://pypi.org/project/hypothesis/).

Comment: One thing ive came to notice. Ive done what you said. Made a `class TestTotalValue(u.TestCase)` with multiple tests, with the same structure (testing multiple functions that should do the same thing, but with different implementations). If one test fails, i get the `seed` and the `(i = x)` on top. However, if multiple test fails, it wont provide me with a message at all, for any of the failed tests. Is this behaviour expected?

Comment: @Snusifer it's hard to tell exactly what you are doing without an example. If you're using the standard library subtests, try also using `self.assertEqual()` inside instead of a plain `assert` statement. It should test all iterations even if some of them fail inside the `with` (but not outside it).